# Issue with First step in DB2 Enterprise Server Edition Version 9.7

Tags: db2

I installed `IBM DB2 Enterprise Server Edition Version 9.7`

window is not opening so because of this I couldn't able to create a sample database.

Is there any way to manually download the sample database & connect to DB2?

Answer (score 0):

Try the command `db2sampl` and start reading some basic documentation.